# Joomla - renderModule function strips javascript

Tags: joomla, module

please help, I've a problem with Joomla's function renderModule.. I am trying to render module with this function, but it unfortunately strips javascript from the the rendered module.
I use the function in my own module which includes other modules according to current article..
The code is as following:

```
<?php
$moduleType = "j15html";
$moduleName = "test";
$option = JRequest::getVar( 'option', '' );

$view = JRequest::getVar( 'view', '' );

$id = JRequest::getInt( 'id', 0 );

$moduleName .= $id;
//echo $view;
if ( $option == "com_content" && $view == "article"  ) {
//echo $moduleName;
 $module = JModuleHelper::getModule($moduleType, $moduleName);
 //print_r($module);
  if ( ! empty( $module ) ) {
   $attribs = array();
   echo JModuleHelper::renderModule( $module, $attribs ); 
  }
}
```

When I set the position of the included module to any position used in my template and set it to displat in particular menu section, it renders properly even with javascript and so on..
Any advices how to make this thing working?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention which version of Joomla you're using - but you may want to check out [SOURCERER](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/custom-code-in-content/5051) it keeps coding how you put it and does not strip out extra coding.

Make sure you read the how-to so you know how to use it because it can seem a little confusing at first, but it has a button to 'change the tags' from < to << or [ which do not get stripped out by the WYSIWYG editor in Joomla!.

Of course, that could be your issue also, if your WYSIWYG editor is on (by default it is) and you're inputting code - it strips it.  An easy way is to just turn it off under global options, then when you save the code doesn't get stripped.  Just turning off the WYSIWYG editor is the quick/easy/simple solution - but if you turn it back on and open that module again, the code will be gone.  So it can be a tricky solution if others may like using the editor or if you're using lots of custom code around your side.  In that case the plugin I mentioned above is a great solution.

Comment: actually I have disabled WYSIWYG editor..The code is workking when the module is displayed as standard..(when it has set position and the same position is then mentioned in template and it has set the menu items where it should be displayed)..It only gets stripped when rendering through the renderModule function..
Oh..I the site is running Joomla 1.5

Comment: Ah!  Thanks for the clarification.  Unfortunately I'm not sure why the renderModule function is stripping it out in that case.  I'll be interested to see what the solution will be.  Have you looked at that function to see what it does specifically?

Comment: So..I put lot of effort into trying make this working, but unfortunately I did not achieved it so far.
There is really weird behaviour of the getModule method in Joomla. I tried to print_r variables during running that method and it's really weird. It calls method JModuleHelper::_load..There is an array named $modules..when I print_r the array, the script runs (so its still there), but the $module->content does not contain it (huge wtf)..Another wtf comes only bit further because after the _load method returns the same array and I print_r it, it does not run the javascript..

Comment: So please is there another way how to render module in joomla?:D

Comment: Hm..after another couple of hours trying to solve that it is now working..But I am not sure why..I created all my modules again. maybe there was a mistake. I really hate this kind of errors..When things get solved and you dont know why:D

Comment: I'm with you - those kind of errors are the worst!  Sometimes it's something really simple that gets overlooked and you don't check it because... well... it's that simple!  Glad you got it fixed up!